# PHP code for every single page of a website

Tags: php

I am a beginner in web development. I know that the `index.php` file provides the foundation of a website. With some template design, we can re-use the headers and footers for many of the pages of the site. For the content, suppose I have the following:

```
<?php include 'content.php';?>
```

However, each page contains unique content. Therefore, this makes me think that for every page that I have, I need to create a separate PHP file. For instance, for page one I create a `content_one.php` file and for page two I create a `content_two.php` etc. Am I correct in my assumption? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So many options and possible solutions to what you are asking (at least what I think you are asking). Based on your proposed theory, what problems did you encounter? How did you differentiate between `page one` and `page two`?

Comment: Well, so far, I haven't encountered any problems. I was just wondering whether there was a better way of doing this, other than the way that I proposed. I'm a bit sceptical about my code during the beginning stages, and is concerned that the way I am doing is far from best practises. I know that this question may be so trivial for someone who is even slightly familiar with php, but for a beginner like myself, I want to be certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's pretty much the standard pattern for those coming to PHP from a predominantly HTML background. Typically they'll start with a multiple-page HTML site, each page with its own HTML file. As the site grows, they'll realize there is a lot of duplicated markup (header, footer, etc) and it becomes tedious to keep it all consistent. The solution is to rename their pages with a `.php` extension so the files are processed before they're served to the client, then the duplicate markup is removed and placed in an include file. The files are then all updated to pull in the content from the file using either `include` or `require`.

I wouldn't say that approach is wrong. This is exactly how I came to PHP oh so many years ago! But it isn't really the best in the long run. Realize that it's a stepping stone and as you learn more you'll realize what proper architecture/design looks like.

I don't know the true level of your programming experiences. When you're comfortable, you make want to look into some web frameworks, like [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/) and [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). In these frameworks, the `index.php` file serves as a central entry point. All requests go through index and then are dispatched to different classes/methods/functions depending on the requested path. This is when your site starts to resemble a web application more than a web site from the development standpoint.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your informative response! I appreciate what you wrote in the last paragraph about the web frameworks. I will definitely take a look! Now that I think about it, I believe Wordpress does something similar; their central entry point is indeed the index.php, so probably they are using one of the frameworks that you mentioned! Anyway, thanks a bunch again!

Comment: You're welcome!  Wordpress doesn't use a framework - it's a monster all of its own :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this is to make your index.php the front controller for the site.

You do this with a case statement like this:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'home';

switch ($page) {
   case 'faq' :
        require_once('includes/faq.php');
        exit;
   case 'blog' :
        require_once('includes/blog.php');
        exit;
   case 'home':
   default:
      require_once('includes/home.php');
}
```

Then your menus just need to use `www.test.com?page=blog` and adding new pages is as simple as putting the code and markup for that page in a new script in the includes directory and updating your menu code.

With rewrite rules, you can easily have url's like `www.test.com/page/blog`

It's a simple and effective way to handle routing.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty neat! I'll try to test this structure out, but I'm already optimistic that this will organise my code quite a bit! Thank you!